# Visual Studio Code LLDB on macOS error when starting debugging session

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, lldb, vscode-debugger

I'm trying to configure Visual Studio Code for compiling/debugging C++ programs on macOS. I am using the following [launch.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/launch-json-reference) file:

[image]

When I try and start a debugging session, I get the following error:

```
Warning: Debuggee TargetArchitecture not detected, assuming x86_64.
ERROR: Unable to start debugging. Unexpected LLDB output from command "-exec-run". process
exited with status -1 (attach failed ((os/kern) invalid argument))
The program '/path/to/Development/C++/helloworld/main' has exited with code 42
(0x0000002a).
```

It is worth mentioning that I am using an [MacBook (M1)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook_Air_(Apple_silicon)#Third_generation_(Retina_with_Apple_silicon)), so x86_64 is not the correct architecture. I'm assuming that this is the reason for the error.

I can't seem to find any reference to this error anywhere online. How can I solve this?

Adding "targetArchitecture": "ARM64" removed the warning, but it does not fix the error.

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and take the appropriate [action](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67270447/edit). Thanks in advance.

Comment: I downvoted this question for having images of codes.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

I had the same problem and I found that Visual Studio Code does not support a debugger for ARM64 binaries yet. Here is the issue [link](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/7035).

However, it works if you use another extension. Install **CodeLLDB** and set `"type": "lldb"` in *launch.json* like below.

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
      {
        "name": "clang++ - Build and debug active file",
        "type": "lldb",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
        "args": [],
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "preLaunchTask": "clang++ build active file"
      }
    ]
  }
```

You can check [quick start](https://github.com/vadimcn/vscode-lldb#quick-start) guide of vscode-lldb repository.

Note that preLaunchTask's value should be the same as the label's value in your *task.json* file.

Comment: As a Neovim user, I can also confirm that codelldb is far more stable and easy to setup than cpptools. (cppdbg/cpptools has problems killing the debuggee and `lldb` after the debugging session)

Answer (score 1):

Using cargo's config instead of "program" resolved it for me (using Rust and LLDB).

```
{
  "name": "(OSX) Launch",
  "type": "lldb",
  "request": "launch",
  "cargo": {
    "args": ["build", "--manifest-path", "${fileDirname}/../Cargo.toml"]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make an executable with the command:

```
gcc file_name.c -g
```

#### File *launch.json*

"targetArchitecture": "x86_64",

Answer (score 0):

In 2023, the LLDB debugger works for Rust on macOS Monterey 12.5.1 with an M1 chip:

**I installed the CodeLLDB extension**.  In the vscode menu bar, I clicked on `View > Extensions`, then in the search text box I typed in `CodeLLDB`, then I clicked on "install".

**I configured launch.json**.  I created my program with `cargo new`, and in vscode I made sure that the top directory in Explorer (View > Explorer) was my program's directory, e.g. guessing_game3.  I did that by clicking `File > Open Folder`, then navigating to my program's top level directory.

Then I clicked on the `Run and Debug` icon on the left side of vscode:

[image]

which produced this view:

[image]

If you see this instead:

[image]

that means you already have a .vscode directory in your program's directory **OR** one of your program's parent directories.  I did that by accident somehow, so I went into one of the parent directories and deleted the `.vscode` directory:

```
one_of_my_programs_parent_dirs% rm -rf ./.vscode
```

Okay, back to the previous image....I clicked on "Create a launch.json file", and a dialog box popped up:

[image]

I clicked "Yes".  That created a .vscode directory in my program's directory, which contained the `launch.json` file:

[image]

That's it.  The debugger worked.  You can read about how to use the debugger here:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging