# Can't debug C program with VSC at M1 Mac

Tags: c, debugging, visual-studio-debugging, vscode-debugger, apple-m1

I'm running Visual Studio Code at MacBook Air (M1, 2020) with Mac OS Big Sur 11.4 (20F71)

and I have the following configuration at launch.json file:

```
}   
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        
        {
            "name": "clang - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "lldb",
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: clang build active file"
        }
    ]
}
```

---

When I'm trying to debug the following Hello World program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    printf ("Hello World");
    return 0;
}
```

as a result, at the debug console, I'm getting the following:

```
Warning: Debuggee TargetArchitecture not detected, assuming x86_64.

ERROR: Unable to start debugging. Unexpected LLDB output from command "-exec-run". process exited with status -1 (attach failed ((os/kern) invalid argument))

The program '/hellowolrd' has exited with code 42 (0x0000002a).
```

---

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VSCode LLDB on MacOS error when starting debugging session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67270447/vscode-lldb-on-macos-error-when-starting-debugging-session)